# What is the use of a sharepoint crawl?

Tags: search, sharepoint, search-indexing

I know a crawl is used to update the index in order to do a search on sharepoint quickly. But what I do not understand why one needs a crawl in the first place!

Whenever a page is updated, added or changed, why isn't the index updated in that very instance? This would mean the index is up-da-date immedeately, and you don't have to run a 'crawl' ever. Wouldn't that be much easier?

Maybe I am missing the big picture here, so any insights would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Crawling and indexing are very closely related. Crawling in web search is where you follow all the links on a page to find all the other pages it links to. It's been a standard way to describe the way web search engines gather pages for a very long time. Once a set of pages has been collected by a crawl, the indexing process starts collecting data from the pages that helps with retrieval. A query by a user takes advantage of the index to return relevant pages quickly.

SharePoint 2013 added a new option, called Continuous Crawl, to help reduce the delay of crawl. Keep in mind that all of these search processes, crawling, indexing and querying are very resource intensive. Delays can be reduced, in part, by by more and larger servers and adding them into the search farm.

## Reference

- [How web search engines work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_search_engine#How_web_search_engines_work)) wikipedia
- [Difference between SharePoint Continous Crawl and Incremental Crawl](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84913/difference-between-continious-crawl-and-incremental-scheduled-crawl) sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1):

the crawl component will help you get the properties from different items that are seen through/configured/referenced in the content sources ( which don't have to be only SharePoint sites , it can also be external sites/links/people..etc ) 
it will generate the crawled properties which will be feeding the content processing component. why ? well cause that would represent the schema for the search that you can change as your business needs requires . 
by that i mean that you can set extra properties ( such as a priority for a property such as Author) to the managed properties( that you can see the full list if you open the search schema from the SA admin page) 
after updating or not the search schema using the content processing step, data will be written in the index files ( that don't necessarily live in the c:\ drive)
doing so will help you get a more accurate index than just filling it directly from the sites..

hope that would help a little :)